# wxPython - cannot press on BUTTON or move SLIDER

Tags: python, button, slider, wxpython, boxsizer

WORKS ON (Linux Mint, Python 2.7.5, wxPython 2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode)), but not with Windows 7. Can someone else with Windows try?

I have created a GUI with a great layout using wxPython. However, button and slider don't work in one of the panels. Please provide some guidance for me. (code runs fine, but button cannot be pressed and cannot move slider)

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.SetSize((1300, 700))
        self.SetTitle('GUI made by James')

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('#4f5049')
        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self.panel)
        mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')

        sub_vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        subPanel_top = wx.Panel(mainPanel)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hierarchy_browser = wx.TextCtrl(subPanel_top, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        hbox.Add(hierarchy_browser, proportion = 1, flag = wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM | wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        subPanel_right = wx.Panel(mainPanel)
        wx.StaticText(subPanel_right, -1, "This is custom static text", (10, 10), (300, -1), wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        button = wx.Button(subPanel_right, label = "exit", pos = (500, 100), size = (60, 60)) #can't press for some reason
        slider = wx.Slider(subPanel_right, -1, 50, 1, 100, pos = (320, 10), size = (250, -1), style = wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)  # can't slide for some reason
        slider.SetTickFreq(5, 1)

        hbox.Add(subPanel_right, proportion = 1, flag = wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM | wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        subPanel_top.SetSizer(hbox)

        sub_vbox.Add(subPanel_top, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        subPanel_bottom = wx.Panel(mainPanel)
        text_entry = wx.TextCtrl(subPanel_bottom, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        text_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()  # use sizer to expand TextCtrl
        text_sizer.Add(text_entry, 1, flag = wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT |  wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, border = 10)
        subPanel_bottom.SetSizerAndFit(text_sizer)
        sub_vbox.Add(subPanel_bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        mainPanel.SetSizer(sub_vbox)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(mainPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closebutton, button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.closewindow)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def closebutton(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def closewindow(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    MainWindow(None)
    ex.MainLoop()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code works for me. I can press button and close window. I can move slider too. (Linux Mint, Python 2.7.5, wxPython 2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode))

Comment: WHAT!? I'm using Windows. Don't know how I can test it

Comment: Windows 8,7,Vista,XP or 2000 ? Python version you can get with command `python -V` (big letter "V"). wxPython version you can get with script `import wx; wx.version()`

Comment: Maybe I could run Windows 7 on VirtualBox - but I had to install python and wxPython.

Comment: I edited the problem description already to mention that I am running Windows 7. I have python 2.7.5, wxPython 2.8.12.1 (msw-unicode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your subPanel_right has no size since you simply attached objects to it rather than using a sizer... so when the sizer it is in resizes it its size is none and you cannot click

one solution is to set the size of the panel

```
subPanel_right = wx.Panel(subPanel_top,-1,size=(560,300))
```

you may need to do somehting funny after and do

```
subPanel_right.SetMinSize(560,300)
```

to force it to be that size and not resize (I dunno it worked for me without that, but sometimes I have to do that)

In general you should not mix absolute layouts with Sizer controlled layouts .... for instance one panel with a flexgridbagsizer would probably have sufficed ... or one panel with some tricky boxlayouts

Comment: so the key is using subPanel_top panel, instead of mainPanel